# Wireframe parts in Siemens NX

Tags: cad

This is probably a fairly basic question for seasoned Siemens NX users, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

I have a large assembly and I would like to set certain components to wire frame view, while still viewing other parts as solid bodies. I know it's possible, because apparently I've done it before, but I can't remember or find how I did it.

[image: Wire-frame limit switch in assemble]

I can set the entire assembly to wire frame easily enough, but I would like to set only certain parts to be.

Also, when I go into the part (the limit switch in this case) the part default is NOT wire frame but a solid body. I'm assuming (hoping) there is a setting in the assembly that I can toggle off/on per part as needed. Solidworks had something very similar, but I'm not using NX and am still inexperienced with the available tools.

Hopefully this is an acceptable forum to be asking this!